# Getting buildings that house specific amenities using R?

Tags: r, openstreetmap

I am new using OSM and I am little bit lost here. I managed to get all restaurants in Winterthur, a city in Switzerland using amenity=restaurant. I used the R-package osmdata as follows:

```
q1 <- getbb ("winterthur, switzerland") %>%
      opq () %>%
      add_osm_feature("amenity", "restaurant")
```

I extract the locations as follows:

```
out <- osmdata_sf(q1)
out$osm_points
```

Is there an easy way to find the corresponding buildings (e.g. osm ids), belonging to the amenities.

Comment: A restaurant can either be a *node* or an *area* in OSM. It shouldn't appear as both. The nodes at the polygon locations are the points that make up the building outlines. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ Spacedman Thank you for that information. I am trying to assign (if a point) a restaurant to a building. If I understand you correctly, the easiest way (or at least one way) would be to test whether a point (the restaurant) is inside a polygon (building)?!

Comment: What you get back from OSM is a set of restaurants - some of which are represented as points, and some as polygons. The ones represented by polygons are buildings. The ones represented by points do not have an associated building polygon in the data you downloaded. It is possible you could download **all** building=yes polygons - including those **not** tagged as "restaurant" and some may contain the points you downloaded. Do you want to do that?

Comment: @Spacedman Alright. I guess then this is what I am going to do. It seems like an extensive solution and this is why I wasn't sure whether it is the only approach. Thanks for clarifying things.

Comment: It should be sufficient to download a small buffer *around* restaurant nodes to determine the building they belong to. However if you want to do this for a large number of nodes then download the whole country instead.